# Can you use React.addons.PureRenderMixin with components that use props.children?

Tags: reactjs

Example:

Will this component re-render as expected when `updateName` is called if `MyComponent` uses `React.addons.PureRenderMixin`?

```
...
render() {
    return <MyComponent>
               <HelloWorld name={ this.state.name } />
           </MyComponent>;
}

updateName() {
    this.setState({name: 'Fred'});
}
```

Comment: It appears that props.children is always a new object, even if the children themselves have not changed, which means that PureRenderMixin is effectively useless for components that use props.children, as it will always re-render, even when the children have not changed.

So, you can't use PureRenderMixin on anything that takes children.

Comment: it would be cool if react components themselves were immutable, so that you could easily determine if children have changed

Answer (score 0):

It "renders the same result given the same props and state", so when you call `this.setState({name: 'Fred'})` it will re-render assuming that  `this.state.name !== 'Fred'`

Comment: What I care about is if MyComponent.props.children === nextProps.children

Comment: Because `MyComponent` won't re-render if `MyComponent.props.children === nextProps.children` , when using `React.addons.PureRenderMixin`.